# Azure DevOps agent lacks permission to push to feed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I currently have a self-hosted agent running as a service with under `DOMAIN\admin` account
, who's also the organization admin, (the agent PAT is **full-access**).

My project has a NuGet Feed, with the `[ORGANIZATION]\Project Collection Service Accounts` as Owner and `Project Collection Build Service (ORGANIZATION)` as Contributor. As a "debug" I also added `DOMAIN\admin` to the feed permissions.

I built a pipeline that does the following: Build, Test, Pack, and Nuget Push.

The `Nuget Push` fails with the following error: `403 (Forbidden - User '0a681a12-11c5-4573-ab59-82be15aaabbd' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'ReadPackages'.`

I'm not sure why this happens, the PAT is full access, and the service is under an admin. Any help?

**Edit**

When registering the Agent at the Service account step I get this warning:
`ERR  NativeWindowsServiceHelper] Can't enumerate account rights, return code 3221225524.`

**Edit 2**

I just build a Release Pipeline with the Nuget Push job and worked. Also edited the build pipeline to publish the artifact. Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Azure DevOps Build Pipeline, it will use the Build Service Account to Push the nuget package to Azure Feed.

The Build Service account has two levels: Organization level and Project level.

Project Level: **Your-project-name Build Service (your-collection-name)**

Organization level: **Project Collection Build Service (your-collection-name)**

You need to based on your Pipeline Settings to grant the **Contributor** Role to related Build Service account.

For Yaml Pipeline, you can navigate to **Project Settings -> Settings**  and check the option: **Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines**.

If the option is enabled, it will use Project Level Build Service account, or it will use Organization Level account.

For Classic Pipeline, you need to navigate to **Option tab** and check the **Build job authorization scope**

[image]

If the Pipeline is using the Project level Build Service account, you need to grant the **Contributor** role to **Your-project-name Build Service (your-collection-name)** in Azure Feed -> Settings ->  Permissions.

For example:

[image]

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Manage build service account permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#manage-build-service-account-permissions)